# Two column html layout with stretch-to-fit column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am in search of a 2 column non-`table` layout that behaves like a `table`. and works in IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/YGb2y/
this works but it's a table and as we all know, tables are not the ideal option of layouts. I'll use it if I have to, but I'd like to find a more semantically appropriate way to do this

[image: table]
note how the left column stretches to fit the containing content, and the right column takes up the rest of the available space

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="left">12345</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">123456</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">1234567</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">12345678</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">123456789</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">1234567890</td><td class="right">...</td></tr>
</table>

table
{
    width:100%;
}
.left
{
    width:1px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.right
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

I tried to change this to use ul/li/div but I can either set a fixed width or percentage left column. There's no `width:stretch-to-fit`.
http://jsfiddle.net/cj6PR/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="left">12345</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">123456</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">1234567</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">12345678</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">123456789</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">1234567890</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
}
li
{
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li div
{
    padding:5px;
}
.left
{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.right
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

[image: problems]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with

http://jsfiddle.net/cj6PR/4/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="left">12345</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">123456</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">1234567</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">12345678</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">123456789</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
    <li><div class="left">1234567890</div><div class="right">...</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
li
{
    display:table-row;
}
li div
{
    display:table-cell;
}
.left
{
    width:1px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.right
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

JS (IE7 hack)

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7)
{
    $("ul").wrapInner("<table />");
    $("li").wrap("<tr />");
    $("li div").wrap("<td />");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a fixed width if you dont know the max width of the content.

You can't get them to one width that is still flexible w/o javascript if you use 1 div per line.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2un/

Comment: that works, but ul/li is more semantically correct - i'd like to find a solution that uses that if possible

Comment: This is not a good solution, see this slightly edited fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2un/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2un/1/) where more lines are added to the right column.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the width with a `em` value rather than `%`, that way it'll always be relative to the text-size, thus less likely to not be wide enough.

Alternatively you can specify a `min-` and a `max-width`in `px` to prevent the layout from 'breaking' too much. Actual values of these you'd have to figure out yourself.

( referring to your `.left` css rule )

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:15em; /* or any other value that you consider wide enough */
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Or

```
.left
{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    min-width: 125px; /* whatever suits your needs */
    max-width: 150px; /* whatever suits your needs */
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

One other alternative is too make your divs behave like a table without actually being a table

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table for more information on that idea.

Comment: the table, table-row, table-cell would be ok, but I need to support IE7 :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, see [updated demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGb2y/1/).

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```